# Navigating carousel using arrow keys

Tags: android, carousel

I created a carousel like [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/146145/Android-3D-Carousel). How can i control the carousel to meet previous and next selected item using arrow keys?

Answer (score 0):

Because someone did not answer my question, I will answer. I resolved that I added two function called moveprevious and movenext to the class carousel and it work pretty good.

```
  boolean movePrevious() {
        if (mItemCount > 0 && mSelectedPosition > 0) {
            scrollToChild(mSelectedPosition - mFirstPosition - 1);
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    boolean moveNext() {
        if (mItemCount > 0 && mSelectedPosition < mItemCount - 1) {
            scrollToChild(mSelectedPosition - mFirstPosition + 1);
            return true;
        }   
        else {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

then i call these functions in bellow code.

```
   @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        switch (keyCode) {

        case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_LEFT:
            ////if (movePrevious()) {
                playSoundEffect(SoundEffectConstants.NAVIGATION_LEFT);
                moveNext();

            ////}
            return true;

        case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_RIGHT:
            /////if (moveNext()) {
                playSoundEffect(SoundEffectConstants.NAVIGATION_RIGHT);
                movePrevious();
            ////}
            return true;

        case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_CENTER:
        case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER:
            mReceivedInvokeKeyDown = true;
            // fallthrough to default handling
        }

        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }
```